# Replacing certain letters in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Heyo! Tried everything but can't figure this out. I have a command where you mention an user and from that mention will bot take his ID. But the ID looks like mention (<@!id>) and I need replace that mention into ID only. Here's code.

```
const mentionUser = message.mentions.users.first();
if(args[0] == mentionUser) {
  let object = mentionUser.id;
  id = object.replace('@', '');
} else {
  id = args[0];
}
console.log('ID:', id);
```

I can't figure out if its value, object or array? So I tried every single function to convert it into a string so I can replace certain letters. String(), stringify, regexp etc... Nothing seem to be working.

Console return:

```
ID: <@!191243099123482625>
```

Comment: use .toString(), you can also use typeof() to find out a type. Lastly check if your first condition is even met.

Comment: So it's a string originally. But somehow replace() do not work.

Comment: >Lastly check if your first condition is even met

Comment: Yes, it is. From mentioned user bot will take his ID. That is what it returns in a console. So if I type for example !id @Polkov bot returns <@!id>. But I need that "<@!>" symbols replace with "". So in first condition let object works but id not. If I type !id <id_of_user> (which is second condition) - always works fine.

Comment: The first condition is never met @DávidPeprik. Your `console.log` is actually printing out just `args[0]`, from the `else` statement (regardless of whether you use a mention or an ID in your command). If you put a `console.log` inside your `if` statement you would see it is never reached. See the answer I just posted.

Comment: Try putting a `console.log` in your `if` statement and see for yourself. The `let object` line is never even reached. Plus, `mentionUser.id` is not `<@!id>` (which is a full mention), it is just the `id` part of the mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, your `if` condition is not even being met. You're doing `if (args[0] == mentionUser)` and that is *never true*. As you can see from your console return, `args[0]` looks like: `<@!id>`. Whereas this is what mentionUser looks like as a String: `<@id>`. The exclamation point in the former will make it never match up with the latter, even if they are the same mention.

The exclamation point actually indicates that this is a guild member mention (meaning the user was mentioned in a guild). So the code you have currently would be very close to working if the message were a DM message instead of a guild message.

What you need to do is you need to check if the `mentionUser` even exists (in the event that no user was mentioned at all), and if it does exist you simply need to do `mentionUser.id` to get the user's ID. Replacing is only necessary to ensure that the first arg is a mention, by removing the exclamation point from the first arg. Here's an example:

```
const mentionUser = message.mentions.users.first();

if(mentionUser && args[0].replace('!', '').match(mentionUser)) {
  id = mentionUser.id;
} else {
  //Mention was not in the first arg, treat first arg as an ID instead
  id = args[0];
}

console.log('ID:', id);
```